# Minimum PWM speed of a light to prevent flickering?

Tags: led, pwm, camera

I'm building a PWM controlled LED Panel, and am trying to figure out what the minimum speed should be to prevent any on-film flickering. How would it be possible to calculate this?

Comment: Film? Is this a prop? If you go faster than the frame rate by 20x that's probably enough but I'd want to test it. Also you want to avoid beat frequencies that are visually annoying.

Comment: A general figure is that at 3KHz or above, typical digital cameras seem not to pick up horizontal stripes. For actual films, I don't know, but if I have to guess, many times minimum shutter speed.

Comment: Damn. I bought a max 1.5KHz PWM driver IC. Well, I guess I'il report my results here. Do you reckon that the MOSFET controlled by the pwm signal will smooth the signal a little?

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer: Drive them with DC current, and avoid time-sensitive behavior.

If you must use PWM, see Spehro's comment.

The long answer: examine the time-sensitivity curve of the fastest film you'll ever use (or luminance response time of your camera's electronic sensor (CCD, CMOS) at its highest ISO setting).

Electronic sensors can be very fast. Dalsa has a video camera that can shoot 100 million frames per second. I would use continuous-power lights for that application!